# Get user in rest API endpoint

Tags: javascript, users, rest-api

I'm making some API endpoints that require me to confirm who the user is, and what they can do, before I let them use the endpoint.

However, I can't seem to get the current user.

**My endpoint:**

```php
function register_api_hooks() {
  register_rest_route(
    'bacon', '/user/',
    array(
      'methods'  => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'makinbacon',
    )
  );
}

function makinbacon(WP_REST_Request $request){

    return json_encode(wp_get_current_user());
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );
```

**My fetch in the client:**

```
fetch('/wp-json/bacon/user', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
})
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

The fetch code is included in a normal wordpress page on the same domain and installation of wordpress as the API endpoint. Also, I am logged in as an admin user.

**The result:**

```
{"data":{},"ID":0,"caps":[],"cap_key":null,"roles":[],"allcaps":[],"filter":null}
```

So it seems that the endpoint in itself is working. I'm not getting any errors, and it does return what seems to be a user. Just that the user is empty.

**What else I have tried:**

As some answers in similar questions suggested, I have tried including the global `$current_user`. This gave the same result.

```php
function makinbacon(WP_REST_Request $request){

    global $current_user;

    return json_encode(wp_get_current_user());
}
```

I have also tried setting `credentials` to `include` in the fetch call, as well as trying to change both the fetch call and the endpoint to a GET request.

Everything gives the same empty user.

I also tried to do other things in the endpoint, like creating a post, updating a post, etc. That worked fine.

So far the only thing I haven't been able to do in the endpoint is to fetch information about the current user.

Any ideas?

Comment: See the documentation, which describes what you need to do to recognise the current user: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Thank you! I had actually looked through the documentation on authentication before I started making the endpoint, but I must have overlooked/forgotten this part `If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re logged into WordPress.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jacob Peattie, I was able to solve this issue.

You have to include a nonce from the WordPress Javascript API in your REST API requests if you wish to use information about the current user.

From the [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/):

> If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0,
>   turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re
>   logged into WordPress.

In other words, the endpoint will get excecuted even without a nonce, but any attempt to fetch information about the current user will fail/result in an empty user object.